# ASP.NET process ajax request during batch process

Tags: asp.net

I have ab asp.net form which does a few minutes of processing on postback(button click).I Know this is not ideal but I cannot run this process in an async thread as it uses a control reportviewer which is in Reqd only mode in non primary threads.

Given this limitation as the process is going on I would like to show the status at the client. For this I can fire off Ajax requests to the server to obtain processing status.But since the ASP.NET primary thread for the session is busy rendering the report using the reportviewer control the Ajax requests simply wait until all processing is over. Is there any way to periodically relinquish and regain control of primary thread .This we can allow it to reply to any ajax requests.

I have been researching this problem for a while now.All I need is to render a set of reports in background using the ReportViewer control and provide feedback at client

thanks

Comment: Can we use update panel? so that you can provide some thing like "loading.." etc? or do you want to show the progress like what we can see while copying files (some number in %) ?

Answer (score 0):

That makes no sense.  New AJAX calls from the browser can and will be serviced by any of the available threads in the thread pool.

How are you posting the form?  You would have to start the process with an AJAX request to generate the reports or else the browser will lock up waiting for the return from a normal form post.  This would prohibit additional client side calls to be made to check status.

Comment: Is it possible to check the progress of report generation and display to user?